# how update list status once using php+Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have a list contains `date`, `status` fields.

`Title              OutDate           Status
Content1...       2014-12-11           Stop
Content2...       2014-12-16         Running
Content3...       2014-12-15         Running
Content4...       2014-12-03           Stop`

This is my list above.I want update the field `status` from running to stop automatic when outdate before today.I think query and update using sql when fresh list eveytime is waste resource.I hope I can update the `status` once.

By the way.I dont want to use cronjob.I want to use php.
(Forgive my poor English...)

Comment: Create a cronjob and execute on a schedule time daily and update the table.

Comment: update more details with your question.Your problem is not understandable.

Comment: You can do what @AbhikChakraborty suggest if you got con job permission. Otherwise you can only do it with a sql each time

Answer (score 1):

```
$current=date('Y-m-d');
$curdate=strtotime($current);
$project=strtotime($datz); //$datz is fetched from db

if($curdate > $project) {
    //query
}
```